# Google Drive API - PHP Quickstart sample code has error

Tags: php, gmail, gmail-api

This web page outlines the steps to connect to Google GMAIL API's using OAuth. The link to the web page that has the steps is https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/php. In step 3, you will see in the code that a define statement needs to be update to the path of your client secret json file location.

```
define('CLIENT_SECRET_PATH', __DIR__ . '/client_secret.json');
```

In the getClient function, this variable is used as input to setAuthConfig

```
$client->setAuthConfig(CLIENT_SECRET_PATH);
```

This means that the CLIENT_SECRET_PATH value (a file path) is passed and then decoded from JSON. But wait, it's still a path, not the contents of the file. So, the JSON decode fails and $data is null. Bad things happen from here. :(
[image]

Comment: To be better search-/findable on here I'd recommend to put 'Google Drive API' into the title and the error message you get into the text. Also maybe write yourself an answer to that issue and accept it.

Comment: This is a question and answer site, so unfortunately it's off topic as it is. I would recommend rewording it in the form of a question and answering it yourself with most of what you have here now in your answer.

Comment: You can delete the question, edit it, and undelete it.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback and I have made the changes.

Answer (score 0):

So, here is the solution to the issue. It's very simple and clear that Google didn't test the code before posting. What a shame!

***Original Code:***

```
function getClient() {
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME);
    $client->setScopes(SCOPES);
    $client->setAuthConfig($x);
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
```

***Corrected Code:***

```
function getClient() {
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME);
    $client->setScopes(SCOPES);

    $x = file_get_contents(CLIENT_SECRET_PATH);

    $client->setAuthConfig($x);
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
```

I hope this helps you.
Scott

Comment: Note: The above solution is for version 1.1.7 of the php library. In version 2.0+, this issue has been fixed. To download version 2.0+ you have to use the CLI or update your composer.json file. "google/apiclient": "^2.0" added to the require section.